# how to access a fragment's button in main activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a fragment that has a button in it. on click of the button, it should add a new edit text to the layout dynamically. how do i do that?

main activity:

```
package comx.example.amithy.hw4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.addnew{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container,new BlankFragment(),"add")
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void add() {
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

fragment:

```
    package comx.example.amithy.hw4;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    private addnew mListner;

        public BlankFragment() {
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mListner.add();
                }
            });
        }


    public interface addnew{
            void add();
    }
    }
```

main activity.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

fragment's xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BlankFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Dish"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="245dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.956"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
            android:text="Add Ingredients"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.133" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.267"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.241" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.918"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.238" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Search"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.469"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.946" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

can a button in fragment be accessed from the main activity? and add an edit text below the existing edit text on click of the button Add in fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refactor your `Fragment`'s layout somewhat to get the `EditText` to show below the `Button`, but you should be able to add the view you want by getting a reference to the container view (in this case `ConstraintLayout`) and then just adding it. So, assuming the `ConstraintLayout` has `android:id=@+id='myConstraintLayout'`, you should be able to do this from `MainActivity`:

```
findViewById(R.id.myConstraintLayout).addView(editText);
```

To get it to show below the `Button`, you'll need to either refactor to use a vertical `LinearLayout` in your layout somewhere (and replace the ID above with the ID for that container), or programmatically add all the layout params to the `EditText` so that it displays where you want it.